# How to access LoadBalancer logfile with EFK architecture on Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: logging, kubernetes, efk

I followed this [DigitalOcean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-elasticsearch-fluentd-and-kibana-efk-logging-stack-on-kubernetes) successfully. I can access Kibana, ElasticSearch, and I can see the logs of the counter example.

In my Kubernetes cluster I also have a LoadBalancer under `default`, where I am hosting my website. How can I access its logfile with the EFK architecture I have just setup? Is mine a Kibana limitation? Since I cannot see my loadbalancer in the Kibana dashboard, nor the docker container I am running in it.

Comment: Are you running it in a specific cloud environment ? Do you mean a load balancer which is automatically created for you in managed kubernetes cluster like **GKE** based on a `LoadBalancer` `Service` definition ?

Comment: @mario I'm running it in DigitalOcean and exactly as you said, I have a LoadBalancer Service for which I would like to fetch the logfile through the EFK architecture.

Comment: But from your k8s cluster perspective it's only a `Service` for which you don't have any logs. Since this load balancer is not running as a `Pod` on your k8s cluster, in other words it's not part of your workload, running on this cluster, I don't think you'll be able to get its logs. Load balancer is created as part of cloud infrastructure.